# images don't appear when i press on phone photos - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

images don't appear when i press on show imgs using collapse method , how to fix problem

model.py :

```
class Mobile_Images(models.Model):
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Mobile, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
```

admin.py:

```
class Mobile_ImagesAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Mobile_Images

class MobileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'name')
    inlines = [Mobile_ImagesAdmin]
    class Meta:
       model = Mobile

admin.site.register(Mobile,MobileAdmin)
```

views.py :

```
def mobile_posts(request,slug):
    mobile_posts = get_object_or_404(Mobile, slug=slug)
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()
    phone_images = Mobile_Images.objects.all()
    context = {'mobile_posts':mobile_posts,'best_posts' : best_posts,'phone_images':phone_images}
    return render(request,'mobile/mobile_posts_page.html', { 'mobile_posts': mobile_posts,'best_posts' : best_posts,'phone_images':phone_images })
```

html page :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-controls="#phone_pic" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#phone_pic" style="background-color:#7952b3;border-radius:10px"> phone photos </button>
<div id="phone_pic" class="collapse">  <br> 
      <img src="{{phone_images.images}}" alt="" height="300px" width="500px" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
</div>
```

so when i use the code in html `src="{{phone_images.images}}"` it don't show all photos that i uploaded before , how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML page you used `{{ phone_images.images }}` but `phone_images` is not an image object, it's the entire queryset of all mobile images. So rather than passing it to the image src we want to loop over the queryset and apply the img tag to each image.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-controls="#phone_pic" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#phone_pic" style="background-color:#7952b3;border-radius:10px"> phone photos </button>
<div id="phone_pic" class="collapse">  <br>
      {% for image in phone_images %}
        <img src="{{ image.images.url }}" alt="" height="300px" width="500px" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
      {% endfor %}
</div>
```